# Node express cannot get static file

Tags: node.js, express

This is the picture of my server
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GA57RyYsc5ik1pSlLhAGtgGjbp_vLFoH/view?usp=sharing

When I go to http://localhost:3000/

I get the error message: Cannot Get/

myserver.js

```
// TODO: mount the tigers route with a a new router just for tigers
// exactly like lions below
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
var _ = require('lodash');
var morgan = require('morgan');

var lionRouter = require('./lions');
var tigerRouter = require('./tigers');

app.use(morgan('dev'))
app.use(express.static('client'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
// this is called mounting. when ever a req comes in for
// '/lion' we want to use this router
app.use('/lions', lionRouter);

app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  if (err) {
    res.status(500).send(error);
  }
});


app.listen(3000);
console.log('on port 3000');
```

Comment: it looks like you can only route to `/lions`

Comment: any request hits / will use app.use(express.static('client'));

Comment: This is because you are not sending anything on '/' route, app.route('/*')
    .get(function(req, res) {
      res.sendFile(path.resolve(app.get('client') + '/index.html'));
    });

Comment: `app.use(express.static('client'));` is going to map any path inside `client` as `/` but you cannot route to folders... you can have `client/images/foo.png` and route it as `/images/foo.png`, but not folders.

Comment: https://github.com/FrontendMasters/api-design-node check this git. I clone this step-4. But even branch step-1 I cannot get static files

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are trying to visit any url on the browser , then browser makes a GET request to that url, in your case you are not sending any response on the url: "http://localhost:3000/. You can try something like this.

```
app.route('/*')
.get(function(req, res) {
res.sendFile(path.resolve("./client") + '/index.html'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the naming you used, it shows **myserver.js** instead of **server.js** as in the picture you uploaded.

Check your routing on line 10 of you code

```
var lionRouter = require('./lions');
var tigerRouter = require('./tigers');
```

. try this edited codes

server.js

```
// TODO: mount the tigers route with a a new router just for tigers
// exactly like lions below
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
var _ = require('lodash');
var morgan = require('morgan');

var lionRouter = require('./server/lions');
var tigerRouter = require('./server/tigers');

app.use(morgan('dev'))
app.use(express.static('client'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
// this is called mounting. when ever a req comes in for
// '/lion' we want to use this router
app.use('/lions', lionRouter);

app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  if (err) {
    res.status(500).send(error);
  }
});


app.listen(3000);
console.log('on port 3000');
```

Comment: please checkout step-2-fix branch github.com/FrontendMasters/api-design-node. I think the code works but the problem is my computer? I clone this and get error when requests to "/".

Comment: you mean this: "create a basic server with express that will send back the index.html file on a GET request to '/' it should then send back jsonData on a GET to /data" or `git branch -r | grep -v '\->' | while read remote; do git branch --track "${remote#origin/}" "$remote"; done
git fetch --all
git pull --all`?

Comment: I mean the code here https://github.com/FrontendMasters/api-design-node/blob/step-2-fix/server/server.js works fine but my computer get error when I open localhost:3000. The problem is my computer, not the code I think?

Comment: When I open localhost:3000 I should get the static html and css files but I got error

Comment: this solved my problem 
app.use(express.static('../client')); But other computer does not need to

Answer (score 0):

Express static directory is given client but it is present on parent directory.
So i have resolve this issue with path module and now this will work for you.

```js
// TODO: mount the tigers route with a a new router just for tigers
// exactly like lions below
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
var _ = require('lodash');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var path = require('path')

var lionRouter = require('./lions');
var tigerRouter = require('./tigers');

app.use(morgan('dev'))
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client')));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
// this is called mounting. when ever a req comes in for
// '/lion' we want to use this router
app.use('/lions', lionRouter);

app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  if (err) {
    res.status(500).send(error);
  }
});


app.listen(3000);
console.log('on port 3000');
```

Answer (score -2):

Your code works fine after commenting the following three lines of your code:

```
var lionRouter = require('./lions');

var tigerRouter = require('./tigers');

app.use('/lions', lionRouter);
```

Check if any error is present in LionsJS.

Comment: please checkout step-2-fix branch https://github.com/FrontendMasters/api-design-node. I think the code works but the problem is my computer? I clone this and get error when requests to "/".

Comment: using step-2-fix branch,  i can see lion create form page.

Comment: That's why I think the problem is my computer, not the code. But I do not know what is the problem